# UPDATE Button not working in VB . and no error is showing

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnHREmployeeInfoUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHREmployeeInfoUpdate.Click

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    datafile = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication7\WindowsApplication7\Tea.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connString

    'to update employee status ' not working
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "update[HR_Employee_Details]set[Status]='" & cboHREmployeeInfoStatus.Text & "'Where[EmployeeID]='" & txtHREmployeeInfoNewEmployeeID.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("not updated", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Update fail")
    End Try
    MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Updated")

    myconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that you are missing a lot of spaces in your query string

Comment: Actually i have done with the space also, but its just not working.

Comment: Yikes, the sql injection issue in there is scary, local Access DB or not!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes it is .

Answer (score 6):

There are some **really bad** patterns in that code, and as so often happens just updating the code to use better practice will help find the underlying problem. You'll need to read the comments below to see exactly how:

```
'Isolate and group the DB access in it's own class, module, or class library.
'ALL access to the database in the application should run through here.
Public Module DB

    'Move these out of the individual methods, so you don't 
    'have to repeat them everywhere
    Private Readonly Property provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Private Readonly Property datafile As String = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication7\WindowsApplication7\Tea.accdb"
    Private Readonly Property connString As String = provider & datafile

    'Each query gets its own public method in this module, 
    'but everything else should be marked Private
    Public Sub UpdateEmployeeStatus(NewStatus As String, EmployeeID As Integer)
        'Ole provider for ADO.Net uses ? As parameter placeholders.
        'This string could be a CONSTANT!
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE [HR_Employee_Details] SET [Status]= ? WHERE [EmployeeID]= ?"

        'The Using block will guarantee your connection is 
        'closed, even if an exception is thrown.
        'The old code could have leaked connection objects 
        'when there were exceptions.
        'Also, ADO.Net works **much** better when you 
        'create new connection objects for most queries.
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString), _
              cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

            'I have to guess at parameter types here.
            'You should change this to use exact types & 
            'lengths from the database.
            'ADO.Net will figure out what value goes to 
            'what parameter based on the order of the 
            'placeholders in the sql string.
            'These parameters are the ONLY correct 
            'way to include data in an sql command. 
            'Anything else leaves you open to sql injection.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = NewStatus
            'If this is not an integer, change it to correct type.
            'But I wanted to be sure to show two different 
            'parameter types
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = EmployeeID

            'wait as long as possible to call Open
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using 'No need to call conn.Close() -- the Using block took care of it
    End Sub
End Module

Private Sub btnHREmployeeInfoUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHREmployeeInfoUpdate.Click
    'Exception handling can still live in the UI
    Try
        'Again: integer here is just to demonstrate a 
        'different parameter type.
        'If your employee IDs really are strings, it's 
        'easy to remove this.
        Dim EmployeeID As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtHREmployeeInfoNewEmployeeID.Text)
        DB.UpdateEmployeeStatus(cboHREmployeeInfoStatus.Text, EmployeeID)
        MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        'This is where your real problem was!
        'This catch block hid the detail from the exception 
        'you would need to solve the problem!
        'If you don't want to show this to the user, which 
        'is reasonable, you can at least log it somewhere.
        'Once you see the exception message, it will probably 
        'be much clearer how to fix the issue.
        MsgBox($"Error updating the database:{vbCrLf}{Ex.Message}", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Not Updated")
    End Try    
End Sub
```

But so you don't feel like the "good" code needs to be so much longer, here it is again with the comments removed. Especially note how clean the event handler method has become.

```
Public Module DB
    Private Readonly Property provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Private Readonly Property datafile As String = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication7\WindowsApplication7\Tea.accdb"
    Private Readonly Property connString As String = provider & datafile

    Public Sub UpdateEmployeeStatus(NewStatus As String, EmployeeID As Integer)
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE [HR_Employee_Details] SET [Status]= ? WHERE [EmployeeID]= ?"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString), _
              cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = NewStatus
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = EmployeeID

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module

Private Sub btnHREmployeeInfoUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHREmployeeInfoUpdate.Click
    Try
        Dim EmployeeID As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtHREmployeeInfoNewEmployeeID.Text)
        DB.UpdateEmployeeStatus(cboHREmployeeInfoStatus.Text, EmployeeID)
        MsgBox("Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox($"Error updating the database:{vbCrLf}{Ex.Message}", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Not Updated")
    End Try    
End Sub
```

Comment: I just recently found out about using a single Using block for Connection and Command. Saves on indenting. I tried and failed at this in C#, finding out that each using block must have objects of a single type. Comment?

Comment: @Mary In C#, you stack `using` blocks directly on top of each other with no braces until the last `using`... or you did before C# 8. In the new C# this will change to `using var`. For VB.Net, this is a kind of a cheat, where it is technically possible to leak the trailing `IDisposable`... but  more practically, in many years using and promoting this pattern I've never heard of it actually causing a bug on a ADO.Net Command object paired with an ADO.Net Connection.

Comment: Thank you for the C# instructions. In Rockford Lhotka's blog there is some interesting info on disposing commands. http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/DisposeYourCommandObjects.aspx  Admittedly it is quite old (2004) .